# Spring Integration 3 Parallel Independent WebFlux OutboundGateway Calls

Tags: spring-integration

Please suggest a pattern to make 3 parallel `WebFlux OutboundGateway` calls which have different request and response payloads. Is `ScatterGather` a good pattern for this usecase? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PublishSubscribeChannel` with an `Executor` is always a good start to distribute the same message to different independent subscribers in parallel: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel.

Another one is a `RecipientListRouter`, but with this one you have to ensure an async behavior for every  single recipient: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter.

The Scatter-Gather has no async configuration. Its responsibility is slightly different: send to all and wait for some gathered reply. Of course, you can configure it for the mentioned async `PublishSubscribeChannel`, but I believe that's fully different story and does not reflect your request in the question.

Comment: Thanq, `PublishSubscribeChannel` seems a better option.

Comment: Is there a way to know when all 3 calls have completed, like an `Aggregation`?

Comment: Right, and aggregator is a good way. See `PublishSubscribeChannel.applySequence` option for convenience: if all results are sent to the same aggregator, they are going to be grouped by default.